# Плагин для динамического изменения селектов

Tags: jquery, плагин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим мы выбрали в правом селекте 15, в левом должен появится диапазон выбора от 10 до 15. 
Или допустим выбрали в левом 12, чтобы в правом был выбор с 13 до 20.

Вообщем чтобы список селекта принимал логичные значения.

Comment: может быть, "логичные" значения?

Comment: Советую прочитать про такую конструкцию как [Switch](https://learn.javascript.ru/switch). С её помощью вы сможете настроить условия для вашего селекта, которые вам нужно будет показать.Довольно объемный вариант но по своему не плох.

Answer (score 1):

Такое и без плагина можно сделать.

```js
// этот кусок кода не понадобится
for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  var option = $('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
  $('#start, #finish').append(option);
}
$('#finish').val(23);


//--------------
var maxTime = 23,
  minTime = 0;

// при изменении в селектах
$('#start, #finish').on('change', function() {
  // обновляем граничное время
  minTime = parseInt($('#start').val());
  maxTime = parseInt($('#finish').val());
  // скрываем недоступное время
  $('#start option').each(function() {
    var curTime = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(curTime > maxTime) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
  $('#finish option').each(function() {
    var curTime = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(curTime < minTime) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="start"></select>
<select id="finish"></select>
```